# AngularJS attr binding from parent to child component not working

Tags: angularjs

I've created a simple one module app in AngularJS. the body is wrapped in a controller and this controller fetch dummy data from jsonplaceholder (an array of users). I also created a component and attached it to the same controller, named `<my-comp>` and using attr binding I'm trying to pass the object array I receive from the http call, however it throws the following error:

*angular.js:15697 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Busers%7D%7D&p4=%7Busers%7D%7D*

Can you help me find where I'm making the mistake?
I'll leave a (not) working snippet.

```js
angular.module('mainApp', [])
    .controller("controlador", function($q, $http, $scope) {
        $scope.users = [];

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log('response', response.data)
            $scope.users = response.data;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('response', response)
        })
    })

.component("myComp", {
    bindings: { attr1: '=' },
    controllerAs: "modelo",
    template: '<p ng-repeat="user in attr1">{{user.name}}</p>'
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="mainApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>components binding symbols</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-7oYXeK0OxTFxndh0erL8FsjGvrl2VMDor6fVqzlLGfwOQQqTbYsGPv4ZZ15QHfSk80doyaM0ZJdvkyDcVO7KFA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="controlador">

    <my-comp attr1="{{users}}"></my-comp>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are not parsing the response. Before you assign the response.data, do JSON.parse(response.data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{...}}` means evaluating the expression inside it.
To pass a variable, for example in case of your 2 way binding (`attr1: '='`), you simply need to do `attr1="users"`.

Your snippet where you use the component will then look like this:

```
<body ng-controller="controlador">

    <my-comp attr1="users"></my-comp>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```